# Is there an way to access a shared (networked) scanner on android?

Tags: document-scanner

I recently purchased a networked multifunction machine, and I was excited about its ability to scan via handheld devices using Epson's iPrint. Since I'm keeping the device in a different room from my computer, scanning via my tablet seemed much more useful than running from room to room, making adjustments.

However, I found Epson's android scanning app to be a bit... simplistic. It only scans preset document sizes, at preset resolutions, and only to jpeg or pdf, no lossless formats like png or tiff. I searched for alternative apps, and only found manufacturer specific options. My searching was complicated due to all the "scanning" apps that use the phone's camera, and scanning tools for network security.

So, my question is, does anyone know of any way to access shared, networked scanners and use the more advanced features that you see on desktops?

Comment: Please don't ask for recommendations for an app. Just describe the problem you're trying to solve. See also: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a product?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1289)

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about that rule :) I changed my question slightly to address those concerns.